# rasterio Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I'm using [geemap](https://github.com/giswqs/geemap) to display a raster on a created map.
This lib use `xarray_leaflet` to display the raster and this lib will end up using `rasterio` to manipulate the .tif file.

When I launch my display :

```
m = geemap.Map()
m.add_raster(clip_map, colormap='terrain', layer_name='gfc')
```

I get the following error :

> CRSError: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.

This error is everywhere on SO so I tried to verify if my GDAL_DATA env variable was coorectly set :

```py
import os
import stat
gdal_data = os.environ['GDAL_DATA']
print('is dir: ' + str(os.path.isdir(gdal_data)))
gcs_csv = os.path.join(gdal_data, 'gcs.csv')
print('is file: ' + str(os.path.isfile(gcs_csv)))
st = os.stat(gcs_csv)
print('is readable: ' + str(bool(st.st_mode & stat.S_IRGRP)))

# out 
# is dir: True
#is file: False
#FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/gdal/gcs.csv'
```

going to the glad distrib inb the `NEWS` file, I read that they removed lots of file in 3.0 including `gcs.csv`. So it's no longer included in my folder.

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Try adding a 'PROJ_LIB' environment variable pointing to the location of the proj library. This worked for me with that same error

Comment: The CLI of GDAL is also installed on this machine and it created the PROJ_LIB and GDAL_DATA env variable. If I change it it's not gonna work annymore in all the R scripts that we are using.